# Java program for Adding Digits

Tags: java

Given num = 38, the process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2 has only one digit, return it.
but my function returns 11 ? what is wrong with my logic? Help !!

```
public class Solution {
    public int addDigits(int num) {
    int result=doSum(num);
    return result;
    }

    public static int doSum(int num){
        int sum=0,digit;
        while(num!=0){
            digit=num%10;
            sum+=digit;
            num=num/10;
        }
        if(sum/10!=0){
            doSum(sum);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your main function also.

Comment: you need to say `return doSum(sum);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(sum/10!=0){
    doSum(sum);
}
```

This is what is wrong with your logic. You recursively call `doSum()` on the new sum but you do nothing with the result. So you need to change this to:

```
if(sum/10!=0){
   sum = doSum(sum);
}
```